# date-fns check if date exist in array

Tags: javascript

I'm using date-fns, I can use helpers like isMonday(day) that returns true is if the day is a Monday, or isWithinRange(start, end) to check if a date is within a range, however, is there a way to return true if a date is in an array of dates?

Comment: Are you talking about the js `Date` object or sth custom?

Comment: JS Date Object, could be ISO or UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To easy, just use `Array prototype.some`

```
 const dateInArray = (date, array) => array.some(d => +d === +date);
```